# Deleting Specific Cells In Last Row

Tags: excel, vba

After importing the last row of data from a .csv, I am looking to delete specific cells within that data. I know which columns the data will be in but the row will change as I import new data from the latest .csv file.

How can I "loop" through the last row (variable) and delete the cells that are less than 1.

```vb
Sub ImportCSV()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet, FileName As String, Last_Row As Long
                
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Cell = ActiveCell
    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
           
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv")
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName, , True)
    Last_Row = ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Cell.Resize(1, 48).Value = Range("A" & Last_Row).Resize(1, 48).Value
    wb.Close False
    
    Sheets("Calcs").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Resize(2).FillDown

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically find the last row number, you can use the "UsedRange" object. Here is a VBA proc that may help. You would replace "ImportSheetNameHere" with your sheetname. It loops thru only the last row, and only checks the 1st and 2nd columns, but you could change it as needed:

```
Public Sub DeleteLessThan1()

Dim s, rng, LastRow, Cell

s = "ImportedSheetNameHere"

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).UsedRange
LastRow = rng.Rows.Count

'Do 1st column
Set Cell = rng.Cells(LastRow, 1)
If Cell.Value < 1 Then
    Cell.Value = ""
End If
'Do 2nd column
Set Cell = rng.Cells(LastRow, 2)
If Cell.Value < 1 Then
    Cell.Value = ""
End If
'...Do rest of the columns...

End Sub
```

Comment: I've add my code that I have hacked together to my post. I think I understand what you are doing, but I don't believe it will work given my previous code. And I really want to xlLeft when I find an unwanted value. Thanks again.